# ini4j store method changes the comment character

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, ini4j

I want to change the entry of a key in a section of an ini file. I use the ini4j library. So I wrote the code below. I can change the entry but there are also other changes which I don't want:

- replacement of ";" with "#" which indicates comment lines
- addition of blank lines between sections and comments

So how can I solve it?

this is what I expected:

```
[section1]
key1=40
key2=30
[section2]
key1=10
key2=20
;section3
[section3]
key1=10
key2=20
```

this is the file after editing:

```
[section1]
key1=40
key2=30

[section2]
key1=10
key2=20

#section3

[section3]
key1=10
key2=20
```

My code:

```
public static void setEntry(String filePath, String fileName, String sectionName, String keyName, String entry)
        throws IOException {
    String path = filePath.concat(fileName);
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        Ini ini = new Ini(inputStream);
        ini.getConfig().setStrictOperator(true);
        Section section = ini.get(sectionName);
        if (section != null) {
            if (section.containsKey(keyName)) {
                section.put(keyName, entry);
            }
            else {
                section.add(keyName, entry);
            }
        }
        else {
            section = ini.add(sectionName);
            section.add(keyName, entry);
        }

        File iniFile = new File(path);
        ini.store(iniFile);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change default comment character?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, even when the ini4j can read comments with `;` and `#`, it doesn't save this when you have to write them to an ini file.

If you check the [`AbstractFormatter`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ini4j/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/org/ini4j/spi/AbstractFormatter.java#l25) class of the ini4j project, you can see that the only comment operator that it matters when writes is `#`, if you have access to the source code, you can change it with your custom comment operator and should work.

```
abstract class AbstractFormatter implements HandlerBase
{
    private static final char OPERATOR = '=';
    private static final char COMMENT = '#';    // <--- change this to ';'
    ...
```

As for the empty lines, they are just aesthetics. Again, if you have access to the source code, you can edit it by yourself (commenting [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/ini4j/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/org/ini4j/spi/AbstractFormatter.java#l44) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/ini4j/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/org/ini4j/spi/IniFormatter.java#l42) lines?), but I guess is easier if you just re-format your ini file after being generated by this library and remove all empty lines.